# Should I use either cacerts or local trustore but not both?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a local truststore.jks we use for our app. We pass this to the app using VM Options like so:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<<PATH TO TRUSTSOTRE.JKS>>
```

If we are already using this truststore.jks is there any good reason to import certificates into the cacerts file of our jdk?

Couldn't we just import these certs into out existing truststore.jks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no right or wrong here, and the decision depend on your application the operation and approach to managing security setup.

Personally I would always prefer to use a custom trust store (as you are already doing), only containing the trust path for the endpoints that are required for your app.
This way you would only have to maintain trust for the endpoint(s) you are using.

However, if the app connects to many TLS endpoints using certificates from different CA providers, a trust store based on cacerts could make maintenance easier if/when endpoints changes issuer.
In that case I would advise to **not** change the *cacerts* file in the JRE, but base a custom trust store file on the *cacerts* file for use by the application.

Comment: It's in a development environment and there are less than ten certs involved. IN that case, you would prob advice to keep everything in one custom keystore, right? And so ignore cacerts..

Comment: @COOLBEANS, yes I would. I always prefer to control the issuers I trust, but if there were a lot more, and their issuers are present in cacerts, then I would probably consider using cacerts.